# Lua boolean can't be compared like a numbers?

Tags: c, lua

I use Lua 5.3 C API

I use Lua C API to communicate with the script modeling device.
Lua script describes the behavior of the device.
Here is C function called from Lua

```
static int
lua_get_pin_bool ( lua_State* L )
{
    lua_Number argnum = lua_gettop ( L );
    if ( 1 > argnum )
    {
        out_error ( "Function %s expects 1 arguments got %d\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, argnum );
        return 0;
    }
    int32_t pin_num = lua_tonumber ( L, -1 );
    bool state = get_pin_bool ( device_pins[pin_num]);
    if ( -1 == state )
    {       
        lua_pushnil(L);
        return 1;
    }
    lua_pushboolean ( L,  state);
    return 1;
}
```

And corresponding Lua function that utilizes it (`get_pin_bool` calls `lua_get_pin_bool`)

```
function device_simulate()
    for i = 0, 14 do
        if 1 == get_pin_bool(_G["A"..i]) then
            ADDRESS = set_bit(ADDRESS, i)
        else
            ADDRESS = clear_bit(ADDRESS, i)
        end
    end
    for i = 0, 7 do
        set_pin_bool(_G["D"..i], get_bit(string.byte(rom, ADDRESS), i))
    end
end
```

In Lua `get_pin_bool` is never returned in fact.
`lua_pushboolean` returns and C code works correct.
If I change it to `lua_pushnumber` all works correct. In fact it doesn't affect the logic of library but I can't understand why it corrupts the Lua VM.
I doublechecked state variable in C and it always 0 or 1.

Comment: Is anything actually getting "corrupted" or is your script logic just not working? Because a boolean in lua is never going to `== 1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems I'm too C-addict. Changed to use true/false and everything is OK... My fault

Comment: Don't worry about it. But be careful with how you word your problems. There wasn't any "corruption" here so that was a very misleading title to use. The problem was your comparison didn't work (and a quick print of the result and then a comparison test would have found the problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your script's logic here

```
if 1 == get_pin_bool(_G["A"..i]) then
```

lua is not C. A boolean value is not equal to the number one (or any other number).